# One liner to display which debian packages are missing from one system when compared which another?

Tags: debian, apt

I am looking for a one line command that I could use to list all deb packages that are missing from a newly installed system, packages that are installed on a reference system (old one).

Answer (score 2):

First, generate the referencelist.txt with `dpkg -l > referencelist.txt` on the reference machine.

Then your one-liner looks like:

```
bash -c 'diff <(dpkg -l|sort) <(sort referencelist.txt)'
```

Comment: wouldn't you need to sort your referenceslist.txt too ?

Comment: ... (sort referencelist.txt) ?

Comment: Is it possible to list only the packages that were installed manually and not the dependencies. Quite often we endup having tons on packages that are only dependencies and were not ever installed manually.

Comment: Maybe check out debtree http://collab-maint.alioth.debian.org/debtree/